# MongoSinkConnector: resolving secret throws validation exception

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I am trying to resolve the `connection.uri` using FileConfigProvider, by following this example:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/security.html#externalizing-secrets

I have the following POST request:

```
POST http://localhost:8083/connectors/my-sink/config
{
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
    "topics": "topic",
    "database": "my-database",
    "connection.uri": "${file:/home/appuser/my-file.txt:mongo_uri}",
    "config.providers": "file",
    "config.providers.file.class": "org.apache.kafka.common.config.provider.FileConfigProvider"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "error_code": 400,
    "message": "Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nInvalid value ${file:/home/appuser/my-file.txt:mongo_topic} for configuration connection.uri: The connection string is invalid. Connection strings must start with either 'mongodb://' or 'mongodb+srv://\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`"
}
```

It appears that the config validation is executed before resolving the secret value.
And, for this reason, the value `"connection.uri": "${my-secret}"` is not a valid mongodb connection string.

Is there a possibility to fix this?

Source-code:

```
/MyFolder
├── kafka-connect
│   └── Dockerfile
└── docker-compose.yml
```

```
MyFolder\docker-compose.yml:

version: "3"
services:
    zookeeper:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.0.0
        container_name: zookeeper
        hostname: zookeeper
        ports:
            - "2181:2181"
        environment:
            ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
            ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
            
    kafka:
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.0.0
        container_name: kafka
        hostname: kafka
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper
        ports:
            - "29092:29092"
            - "9092:9092"
        environment:
            KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
            KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
            KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
            KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
            KAFKA_offsets_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
            
    kafka-connect:
        build:
            context: ./kafka-connect
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: kafka_connect
        depends_on:
            - kafka
        ports:
            - "8083:8083"
            
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        container_name: mongo
        restart: unless-stopped
        depends_on:
            - kafka-connect
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

```
MyFolder\kafka-connect\Dockerfile:

FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:6.0.0

COPY ./plugins/ /usr/local/share/kafka/plugins/

ENV CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092
ENV CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka_connect
ENV CONNECT_GROUP_ID=kafka-connect-group
ENV CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=kafka-connect-group-config
ENV CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=connect-group-offset
ENV CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=kafka-connect-group-status
ENV CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
ENV CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
ENV CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
ENV CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
ENV CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins

EXPOSE 8083
```

I create the container using `docker-compose up`.

I configure the `MongoSinkConnector` using the kafka-connect REST endpoints.

[image]

Comment: What version of Kafka Connect are you using?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I am using `confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:6.0.0`. I also updated the question.

Comment: Well, did you add `CONNECT_CONFIG_PROVIDERS` as an environment variable to the container to set the properties mentioned in the linked documentation? Specifically, what does your docker run command/compose file look like?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I updated the question with the code samples

Comment: 1) You shouldn't add ENV to your docker file. Those are all runtime parameters and therefore should be moved to the compose file environment variable section. 2) Since you're using a COPY, you should use a volume, not a custom dockerfile 3) Like I said, you're missing `CONNECT_CONFIG_PROVIDERS`, so can you explain why you expected the file provider to work? Specifically, rather than cat your txt file, you should find `connect-distributed.properties` and compare it to the properties mentioned in the documentation you linked to

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I thought that I can add the config providers using the REST api. Adding `CONNECT_CONFIG_PROVIDERS` solved the problem. Thanks for the tips as well. I am currently trying to learn docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties for setting up the provider are for the Connect worker (the process started by the container), not a specific connector

```
kafka-connect:
       ... 
        depends_on:
            - kafka
            - mongo 
        ports:
            - "8083:8083"
        environment:
            ... 
            CONNECT_CONFIG_PROVIDERS: file 
            CONNECT_CONFIG_PROVIDERS_FILE_CLASS: org.apache.kafka.common.config.provider.FileConfigProvider
```